# Is there a random encounter generator online, for color/minor city detail stuff?

Tags: tools, product-identification, generator

I thought somewhere on [Seventh Sanctum](http://www.seventhsanctum.com) there was a generator that would get me random city encounters, just minor NPC things like so:

> You meet a(n) ANGRY, YOUNG... DWARF SHIELD-MAIDEN... ESCORTING... AN ELDERLY RELATIVE TOURIST
>
> You meet a(n) JOLLY, TALL... HUMAN BAILIFF... KEEPING BOOK ON... THE GLADIATORIAL ARENA

Like that?  But I can't find it.  Maybe it's on a different site?  Maybe I dreamed that such a thing exists?  I'm totally paraphrasing the results of the random generator, it wasn't in that specific format (if it exists).  Can you help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a [4e random generator](http://donjon.bin.sh/4e/random/) on donjon.sh, which isn't 4e specific or anything, although the output doesn't look much like yours.

Abulafia has a ton of generators in the [fantasy category](http://www.random-generator.com/index.php?title=Category:Fantasy) -- check out Fantasy Town and perhaps Fantasy Town Event.

Comment: Fantasy Town Event was the thing I was trying to remember.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Check out the excellent and extensible [Abulafia](http://www.random-generator.com/index.php?title=Main_Page).

If it doesn't have what you want, make your own! It's easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

The best is [Cities from Midkemia Press](http://www.midkemia.com/Products.html). It throughly covers just about all types of city encounters. And the price is reasonable at $5.00 for the PDF

Answer (score 2):

Your OP says you are looking for a generator for said urban function.
Try this generator.

http://chaoticshiny.com/index.php
There are some really funny ones, but there are some Urban mashup charts.
I recommend the Law generator.
"The penalty for stealing animal parts is a few months' imprisonment. 
The penalty for a foreigner endangering a member of a certain bloodline is death. 
The penalty for an official kidnapping a free woman is a warning."

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about your specific generator but http://nine.frenchboys.net/ has a ridiculous number of very useful generators. It is something I recommend for all GMs/DMs just for the resource and the best part about it is that it is free.

If you want to keep it in a file and to choose something at random for flavour, I recommend opening a spread sheet, numbering 1-100 and inserting the list you want before printing it. When you need something, roll the dice to select one and cross it off after you have used it. When you are running low, generate a new list. NPC names and descriptions will never again be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

A newer one that works very well is *Eigengrau's Essential Establishment Generator*: https://eigengrausgenerator.com/

> Eigengrau's Essential Establishment Generator, or EEEG for short, is a tabletop procedural generation tool for towns, npcs, and more. It creates paragraphs of text suitable to be read directly to the players during a game. No longer do you have to simply describe a generic, unnamed tavern as "small".

It starts by generating a simple town and then allows you to flesh out buildings, guilds, NPCs, rumours, shops...

Comment: No worries Crummy! There is no such thing as necroing here. We consider all questions and answers to be ever green. You can even get [a badge](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/necromancer) for quality posts on older questions.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] when you get a chance (you get a badge for that too) and visit the [help] for additional guidance. Thanks for contributing and happy gaming!